# ПОМОГИТЕ. Неделю не могу решить вопрос обхода блоков

Tags: javascript, html, css

Проблема следующая. Есть canvas который на заднем фоне расходится дымчатой краской при движении курсора, но при на ведении на блок, к примеру надпись, перестает работать, только вокруг.  Как сделать, чтобы игнорировать блок, т.е. чтобы краска продолжала следовать за мышкой позади блока непрерывно?
[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/f5j2gpLh/34/)

```
HTML
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<canvas id="pretty-bg"></canvas>
       
  <h1 class="text-take">Как обойти блок</h1>

</body>
</html>


CSS
#pretty-bg {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 660px;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}

.text-take {
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 9;
  font-size: 80px;
}

JS
"use strict";const canvas=document.getElementById("pretty-bg");if(canvas){canvas.width=canvas.clientWidth,canvas.height=canvas.clientHeight;let e={SIM_RESOLUTION:128,DYE_RESOLUTION:512,DENSITY_DISSIPATION:.99,VELOCITY_DISSIPATION:.98,PRESSURE_DISSIPATION:.8,PRESSURE_ITERATIONS:20,CURL:20,SPLAT_RADIUS:.3,SHADING:!0,COLORFUL:!0,PAUSED:!1,BACK_COLOR:{r:0,g:0,b:0},TRANSPARENT:!0};function pointerPrototype(){this.id=-1,this.x=0,this.y=0,this.dx=0,this.dy=0,this.down=!1,this.moved=!1,this.color=[30,0,300]}let n=[],r=[];n.push(new pointerPrototype);const{gl:t,ext:i}=getWebGLContext(canvas);function getWebGLContext(e){const n={alpha:!0,depth:!1,stencil:!1,antialias:!1,preserveDrawingBuffer:!1};let r=e.getContext("webgl2",n);const t=!!r;let i,o;t||(r=e.getContext("webgl",n)||e.getContext("experimental-webgl",n)),t?(r.getExtension("EXT_color_buffer_float"),o=r.getExtension("OES_texture_float_linear")):(i=r.getExtension("OES_texture_half_float"),o=r.getExtension("OES_texture_half_float_linear")),r.clearColor(0,0,0,1);const a=t?r.HALF_FLOAT:i.HALF_FLOAT_OES;let u,v,l;return t?(u=getSupportedFormat(r,r.RGBA16F,r.RGBA,a),v=getSupportedFormat(r,r.RG16F,r.RG,a),l=getSupportedFormat(r,r.R16F,r.RED,a)):(u=getSupportedFormat(r,r.RGBA,r.RGBA,a),v=getSupportedFormat(r,r.RGBA,r.RGBA,a),l=getSupportedFormat(r,r.RGBA,r.RGBA,a)),{gl:r,ext:{formatRGBA:u,formatRG:v,formatR:l,halfFloatTexType:a,supportLinearFiltering:o}}}function getSupportedFormat(e,n,r,t){if(!supportRenderTextureFormat(e,n,r,t))switch(n){case e.R16F:return getSupportedFormat(e,e.RG16F,e.RG,t);case e.RG16F:return getSupportedFormat(e,e.RGBA16F,e.RGBA,t);default:return null}return{internalFormat:n,format:r}}function supportRenderTextureFormat(e,n,r,t){let i=e.createTexture();e.bindTexture(e.TEXTURE_2D,i),e.texParameteri(e.TEXTURE_2D,e.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,e.NEAREST),e.texParameteri(e.TEXTURE_2D,e.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER,e.NEAREST),e.texParameteri(e.TEXTURE_2D,e.TEXTURE_WRAP_S,e.CLAMP_TO_EDGE),e.texParameteri(e.TEXTURE_2D,e.TEXTURE_WRAP_T,e.CLAMP_TO_EDGE),e.texImage2D(e.TEXTURE_2D,0,n,4,4,0,r,t,null);let o=e.createFramebuffer();return e.bindFramebuffer(e.FRAMEBUFFER,o),e.framebufferTexture2D(e.FRAMEBUFFER,e.COLOR_ATTACHMENT0,e.TEXTURE_2D,i,0),e.checkFramebufferStatus(e.FRAMEBUFFER)==e.FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE}function clamp01(e){return Math.min(Math.max(e,0),1)}function isMobile(){return/Mobi|Android/i.test(navigator.userAgent)}isMobile()&&(e.DYE_RESOLUTION=128,e.SHADING=!1),i.supportLinearFiltering||(e.SHADING=!1);class o{constructor(e,n){if(this.uniforms={},this.program=t.createProgram(),t.attachShader(this.program,e),t.attachShader(this.program,n),t.linkProgram(this.program),!t.getProgramParameter(this.program,t.LINK_STATUS))throw t.getProgramInfoLog(this.program);const r=t.getProgramParameter(this.program,t.ACTIVE_UNIFORMS);for(let e=0;e<r;e++){const n=t.getActiveUniform(this.program,e).name;this.uniforms[n]=t.getUniformLocation(this.program,n)}}bind(){t.useProgram(this.program)}}function compileShader(e,n){const r=t.createShader(e);if(t.shaderSource(r,n),t.compileShader(r),!t.getShaderParameter(r,t.COMPILE_STATUS))throw t.getShaderInfoLog(r);return r}const a=compileShader(t.VERTEX_SHADER,"\n    precision highp float;\n\n    attribute vec2 aPosition;\n    varying vec2 vUv;\n    varying vec2 vL;\n    varying vec2 vR;\n    varying vec2 vT;\n    varying vec2 vB;\n    uniform vec2 texelSize;\n\n    void main () {\n        vUv = aPosition * 0.5 + 0.5;\n        vL = vUv - vec2(texelSize.x, 0.0);\n        vR = vUv + vec2(texelSize.x, 0.0);\n        vT = vUv + vec2(0.0, texelSize.y);\n        vB = vUv - vec2(0.0, texelSize.y);\n        gl_Position = vec4(aPosition, 0.0, 1.0);\n    }\n"),u=compileShader(t.FRAGMENT_SHADER,"\n    precision mediump float;\n    precision mediump sampler2D;\n\n    varying highp vec2 vUv;\n    uniform sampler2D uTexture;\n    uniform float value;\n\n    void main () {\n        gl_FragColor = value * texture2D(uTexture, vUv);\n    }\n"),v=compileShader(t.FRAGMENT_SHADER,"\n    precision mediump float;\n\n    uniform vec4 color;\n\n    void main () {\n        gl_FragColor = color;\n    }\n"),l=compileShader(t.FRAGMENT_SHADER,"\n    precision highp float;\n    precision highp sampler2D;\n\n    varying vec2 vUv;\n    uniform sampler2D uTexture;\n    uniform float aspectRatio;\n\n    #define SCALE 25.0\n\n    void main () {\n        vec2 uv = floor(vUv * SCALE * vec2(aspectRatio, 1.0));\n        float v = mod(uv.x + uv.y, 2.0);\n        v = v * 0.1 + 0.8;\n        gl_FragColor = vec4(vec3(v), 1.0);\n    }\n"),f=compileShader(t.FRAGMENT_SHADER,"\n    precision highp float;\n    precision highp sampler2D;\n\n    varying vec2 vUv;\n    uniform sampler2D uTexture;\n\n    void main () {\n        vec3 C = texture2D(uTexture, vUv).rgb;\n        float a = max(C.r, max(C.g, C.b));\n        gl_FragColor = vec4(C, a);\n    }\n"),c=compileShader(t.FRAGMENT_SHADER,"\n    precision highp float;\n    precision highp sampler2D;\n\n    varying vec2 vUv;\n    varying vec2 vL;\n    varying vec2 vR;\n    varying vec2 vT;\n    varying vec2 vB;\n    uniform sampler2D uTexture;\n    uniform vec2 texelSize;\n\n    void main () {\n        vec3 L = texture2D(uTexture, vL).rgb;\n        vec3 R = texture2D(uTexture, vR).rgb;\n        vec3 T = texture2D(uTexture, vT).rgb;\n        vec3 B = texture2D(uTexture, vB).rgb;\n        vec3 C = texture2D(uTexture, vUv).rgb;\n\n        float dx = length(R) - length(L);\n        float dy = length(T) - length(B);\n\n        vec3 n = normalize(vec3(dx, dy, length(texelSize)));\n        vec3 l = vec3(0.0, 0.0, 1.0);\n\n        float diffuse = clamp(dot(n, l) + 0.7, 0.7, 1.0);\n        C.rgb *= diffuse;\n\n        float a = max(C.r, max(C.g, C.b));\n        gl_FragColor = vec4(C, a);\n    }\n"),s=compileShader(t.FRAGMENT_SHADER,"\n    precision highp float;\n    precision highp sampler2D;\n\n    varying vec2 vUv;\n    uniform sampler2D uTarget;\n    uniform float aspectRatio;\n    uniform vec3 color;\n    uniform vec2 point;\n    uniform float radius;\n\n    void main () {\n        vec2 p = vUv - point.xy;\n        p.x *= aspectRatio;\n        vec3 splat = exp(-dot(p, p) / radius) * color;\n        vec3 base = texture2D(uTarget, vUv).xyz;\n        gl_FragColor = vec4(base + splat, 1.0);\n    }\n"),m=compileShader(t.FRAGMENT_SHADER,"\n    precision highp float;\n    precision highp sampler2D;\n\n    varying vec2 vUv;\n    uniform sampler2D uVelocity;\n    uniform sampler2D uSource;\n    uniform vec2 texelSize;\n    uniform vec2 dyeTexelSize;\n    uniform float dt;\n    uniform float dissipation;\n\n    vec4 bilerp (sampler2D sam, vec2 uv, vec2 tsize) {\n        vec2 st = uv / tsize - 0.5;\n\n        vec2 iuv = floor(st);\n        vec2 fuv = fract(st);\n\n        vec4 a = texture2D(sam, (iuv + vec2(0.5, 0.5)) * tsize);\n        vec4 b = texture2D(sam, (iuv + vec2(1.5, 0.5)) * tsize);\n        vec4 c = texture2D(sam, (iuv + vec2(0.5, 1.5)) * tsize);\n        vec4 d = texture2D(sam, (iuv + vec2(1.5, 1.5)) * tsize);\n\n        return mix(mix(a, b, fuv.x), mix(c, d, fuv.x), fuv.y);\n    }\n\n    void main () {\n        vec2 coord = vUv - dt * bilerp(uVelocity, vUv, texelSize).xy * texelSize;\n        gl_FragColor = dissipation * bilerp(uSource, coord, dyeTexelSize);\n        gl_FragColor.a = 1.0;\n    }\n"),d=compileShader(t.FRAGMENT_SHADER,"\n    precision highp float;\n    precision highp sampler2D;\n\n    varying vec2 vUv;\n    uniform sampler2D uVelocity;\n    uniform sampler2D uSource;\n    uniform vec2 texelSize;\n    uniform float dt;\n    uniform float dissipation;\n\n    void main () {\n        vec2 coord = vUv - dt * texture2D(uVelocity, vUv).xy * texelSize;\n        gl_FragColor = dissipation * texture2D(uSource, coord);\n        gl_FragColor.a = 1.0;\n    }\n"),g=compileShader(t.FRAGMENT_SHADER,"\n    precision mediump float;\n    precision mediump sampler2D;\n\n    varying highp vec2 vUv;\n    varying highp vec2 vL;\n    varying highp vec2 vR;\n    varying highp vec2 vT;\n    varying highp vec2 vB;\n    uniform sampler2D uVelocity;\n\n    void main () {\n        float L = texture2D(uVelocity, vL).x;\n        float R = texture2D(uVelocity, vR).x;\n        float T = texture2D(uVelocity, vT).y;\n        float B = texture2D(uVelocity, vB).y;\n\n        vec2 C = texture2D(uVelocity, vUv).xy;\n        if (vL.x < 0.0) { L = -C.x; }\n        if (vR.x > 1.0) { R = -C.x; }\n        if (vT.y > 1.0) { T = -C.y; }\n        if (vB.y < 0.0) { B = -C.y; }\n\n        float div = 0.5 * (R - L + T - B);\n        gl_FragColor = vec4(div, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);\n    }\n"),p=compileShader(t.FRAGMENT_SHADER,"\n    precision mediump float;\n    precision mediump sampler2D;\n\n    varying highp vec2 vUv;\n    varying highp vec2 vL;\n    varying highp vec2 vR;\n    varying highp vec2 vT;\n    varying highp vec2 vB;\n    uniform sampler2D uVelocity;\n\n    void main () {\n        float L = texture2D(uVelocity, vL).y;\n        float R = texture2D(uVelocity, vR).y;\n        float T = texture2D(uVelocity, vT).x;\n        float B = texture2D(uVelocity, vB).x;\n        float vorticity = R - L - T + B;\n        gl_FragColor = vec4(0.5 * vorticity, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);\n    }\n"),h=compileShader(t.FRAGMENT_SHADER,"\n    precision highp float;\n    precision highp sampler2D;\n\n    varying vec2 vUv;\n    varying vec2 vL;\n    varying vec2 vR;\n    varying vec2 vT;\n    varying vec2 vB;\n    uniform sampler2D uVelocity;\n    uniform sampler2D uCurl;\n    uniform float curl;\n    uniform float dt;\n\n    void main () {\n        float L = texture2D(uCurl, vL).x;\n        float R = texture2D(uCurl, vR).x;\n        float T = texture2D(uCurl, vT).x;\n        float B = texture2D(uCurl, vB).x;\n        float C = texture2D(uCurl, vUv).x;\n\n        vec2 force = 0.5 * vec2(abs(T) - abs(B), abs(R) - abs(L));\n        force /= length(force) + 0.0001;\n        force *= curl * C;\n        force.y *= -1.0;\n\n        vec2 vel = texture2D(uVelocity, vUv).xy;\n        gl_FragColor = vec4(vel + force * dt, 0.0, 1.0);\n    }\n"),T=compileShader(t.FRAGMENT_SHADER,"\n    precision mediump float;\n    precision mediump sampler2D;\n\n    varying highp vec2 vUv;\n    varying highp vec2 vL;\n    varying highp vec2 vR;\n    varying highp vec2 vT;\n    varying highp vec2 vB;\n    uniform sampler2D uPressure;\n    uniform sampler2D uDivergence;\n\n    vec2 boundary (vec2 uv) {\n        return uv;\n        // uncomment if you use wrap or repeat texture mode\n        // uv = min(max(uv, 0.0), 1.0);\n        // return uv;\n    }\n\n    void main () {\n        float L = texture2D(uPressure, boundary(vL)).x;\n        float R = texture2D(uPressure, boundary(vR)).x;\n        float T = texture2D(uPressure, boundary(vT)).x;\n        float B = texture2D(uPressure, boundary(vB)).x;\n        float C = texture2D(uPressure, vUv).x;\n        float divergence = texture2D(uDivergence, vUv).x;\n        float pressure = (L + R + B + T - divergence) * 0.25;\n        gl_FragColor = vec4(pressure, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);\n    }\n"),R=compileShader(t.FRAGMENT_SHADER,"\n    precision mediump float;\n    precision mediump sampler2D;\n\n    varying highp vec2 vUv;\n    varying highp vec2 vL;\n    varying highp vec2 vR;\n    varying highp vec2 vT;\n    varying highp vec2 vB;\n    uniform sampler2D uPressure;\n    uniform sampler2D uVelocity;\n\n    vec2 boundary (vec2 uv) {\n        return uv;\n        // uv = min(max(uv, 0.0), 1.0);\n        // return uv;\n    }\n\n    void main () {\n        float L = texture2D(uPressure, boundary(vL)).x;\n        float R = texture2D(uPressure, boundary(vR)).x;\n        float T = texture2D(uPressure, boundary(vT)).x;\n        float B = texture2D(uPressure, boundary(vB)).x;\n        vec2 velocity = texture2D(uVelocity, vUv).xy;\n        velocity.xy -= vec2(R - L, T - B);\n        gl_FragColor = vec4(velocity, 0.0, 1.0);\n    }\n"),x=(()=>(t.bindBuffer(t.ARRAY_BUFFER,t.createBuffer()),t.bufferData(t.ARRAY_BUFFER,new Float32Array([-1,-1,-1,1,1,1,1,-1]),t.STATIC_DRAW),t.bindBuffer(t.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER,t.createBuffer()),t.bufferData(t.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER,new Uint16Array([0,1,2,0,2,3]),t.STATIC_DRAW),t.vertexAttribPointer(0,2,t.FLOAT,!1,0,0),t.enableVertexAttribArray(0),e=>{t.bindFramebuffer(t.FRAMEBUFFER,e),t.drawElements(t.TRIANGLES,6,t.UNSIGNED_SHORT,0)}))();let E,S,D,y,A,_,F,b,U;const L=new o(a,u),w=new o(a,v),C=new o(a,l),I=new o(a,f),B=new o(a,c),P=new o(a,s),N=new o(a,i.supportLinearFiltering?d:m),O=new o(a,g),M=new o(a,p),G=new o(a,h),X=new o(a,T),z=new o(a,R);function initFramebuffers(){let n=getResolution(e.SIM_RESOLUTION),r=getResolution(e.DYE_RESOLUTION);E=n.width,S=n.height,D=r.width,y=r.height;const o=i.halfFloatTexType,a=i.formatRGBA,u=i.formatRG,v=i.formatR;A=createDoubleFBO(2,D,y,a.internalFormat,a.format,o,i.supportLinearFiltering?t.LINEAR:t.NEAREST),_=createDoubleFBO(0,E,S,u.internalFormat,u.format,o,i.supportLinearFiltering?t.LINEAR:t.NEAREST),F=createFBO(4,E,S,v.internalFormat,v.format,o,t.NEAREST),b=createFBO(5,E,S,v.internalFormat,v.format,o,t.NEAREST),U=createDoubleFBO(6,E,S,v.internalFormat,v.format,o,t.NEAREST)}function getResolution(e){let n=t.drawingBufferWidth/t.drawingBufferHeight;n<1&&(n=1/n);let r=Math.round(e*n),i=Math.round(e);return t.drawingBufferWidth>t.drawingBufferHeight?{width:r,height:i}:{width:i,height:r}}function createFBO(e,n,r,i,o,a,u){t.activeTexture(t.TEXTURE0+e);let v=t.createTexture();t.bindTexture(t.TEXTURE_2D,v),t.texParameteri(t.TEXTURE_2D,t.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,u),t.texParameteri(t.TEXTURE_2D,t.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER,u),t.texParameteri(t.TEXTURE_2D,t.TEXTURE_WRAP_S,t.CLAMP_TO_EDGE),t.texParameteri(t.TEXTURE_2D,t.TEXTURE_WRAP_T,t.CLAMP_TO_EDGE),t.texImage2D(t.TEXTURE_2D,0,i,n,r,0,o,a,null);let l=t.createFramebuffer();return t.bindFramebuffer(t.FRAMEBUFFER,l),t.framebufferTexture2D(t.FRAMEBUFFER,t.COLOR_ATTACHMENT0,t.TEXTURE_2D,v,0),t.viewport(0,0,n,r),t.clear(t.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT),{texture:v,fbo:l,texId:e}}function createDoubleFBO(e,n,r,t,i,o,a){let u=createFBO(e,n,r,t,i,o,a),v=createFBO(e+1,n,r,t,i,o,a);return{get read(){return u},get write(){return v},swap(){let e=u;u=v,v=e}}}initFramebuffers();let H=Date.now();function update(){resizeCanvas(),input(),e.PAUSED||step(.016),render(null),requestAnimationFrame(update)}function input(){r.length>0&&multipleSplats(r.pop());for(let e=0;e<n.length;e++){const r=n[e];r.moved&&(splat(r.x,r.y,r.dx,r.dy,r.color),r.moved=!1)}if(e.COLORFUL&&H+100<Date.now()){H=Date.now();for(let e=0;e<n.length;e++){n[e].color=generateColor()}}}function step(n){t.disable(t.BLEND),t.viewport(0,0,E,S),M.bind(),t.uniform2f(M.uniforms.texelSize,1/E,1/S),t.uniform1i(M.uniforms.uVelocity,_.read.texId),x(b.fbo),G.bind(),t.uniform2f(G.uniforms.texelSize,1/E,1/S),t.uniform1i(G.uniforms.uVelocity,_.read.texId),t.uniform1i(G.uniforms.uCurl,b.texId),t.uniform1f(G.uniforms.curl,e.CURL),t.uniform1f(G.uniforms.dt,n),x(_.write.fbo),_.swap(),O.bind(),t.uniform2f(O.uniforms.texelSize,1/E,1/S),t.uniform1i(O.uniforms.uVelocity,_.read.texId),x(F.fbo),L.bind();let r=U.read.texId;t.activeTexture(t.TEXTURE0+r),t.bindTexture(t.TEXTURE_2D,U.read.texture),t.uniform1i(L.uniforms.uTexture,r),t.uniform1f(L.uniforms.value,e.PRESSURE_DISSIPATION),x(U.write.fbo),U.swap(),X.bind(),t.uniform2f(X.uniforms.texelSize,1/E,1/S),t.uniform1i(X.uniforms.uDivergence,F.texId),r=U.read.texId,t.uniform1i(X.uniforms.uPressure,r),t.activeTexture(t.TEXTURE0+r);for(let n=0;n<e.PRESSURE_ITERATIONS;n++)t.bindTexture(t.TEXTURE_2D,U.read.texture),x(U.write.fbo),U.swap();z.bind(),t.uniform2f(z.uniforms.texelSize,1/E,1/S),t.uniform1i(z.uniforms.uPressure,U.read.texId),t.uniform1i(z.uniforms.uVelocity,_.read.texId),x(_.write.fbo),_.swap(),N.bind(),t.uniform2f(N.uniforms.texelSize,1/E,1/S),i.supportLinearFiltering||t.uniform2f(N.uniforms.dyeTexelSize,1/E,1/S),t.uniform1i(N.uniforms.uVelocity,_.read.texId),t.uniform1i(N.uniforms.uSource,_.read.texId),t.uniform1f(N.uniforms.dt,n),t.uniform1f(N.uniforms.dissipation,e.VELOCITY_DISSIPATION),x(_.write.fbo),_.swap(),t.viewport(0,0,D,y),i.supportLinearFiltering||t.uniform2f(N.uniforms.dyeTexelSize,1/D,1/y),t.uniform1i(N.uniforms.uVelocity,_.read.texId),t.uniform1i(N.uniforms.uSource,A.read.texId),t.uniform1f(N.uniforms.dissipation,e.DENSITY_DISSIPATION),x(A.write.fbo),A.swap()}function render(n){null!=n&&e.TRANSPARENT?t.disable(t.BLEND):(t.blendFunc(t.ONE,t.ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA),t.enable(t.BLEND));let r=null==n?t.drawingBufferWidth:D,i=null==n?t.drawingBufferHeight:y;if(t.viewport(0,0,r,i),!e.TRANSPARENT){w.bind();let r=e.BACK_COLOR;t.uniform4f(w.uniforms.color,r.r/255,r.g/255,r.b/255,1),x(n)}null==n&&e.TRANSPARENT&&C.bind(),e.SHADING?(B.bind(),t.uniform2f(B.uniforms.texelSize,1/r,1/i),t.uniform1i(B.uniforms.uTexture,A.read.texId)):(I.bind(),t.uniform1i(I.uniforms.uTexture,A.read.texId)),x(n)}function splat(n,r,i,o,a){t.viewport(0,0,E,S),P.bind(),t.uniform1i(P.uniforms.uTarget,_.read.texId),t.uniform1f(P.uniforms.aspectRatio,canvas.width/canvas.height),t.uniform2f(P.uniforms.point,n/canvas.width,1-r/canvas.height),t.uniform3f(P.uniforms.color,i,-o,1),t.uniform1f(P.uniforms.radius,e.SPLAT_RADIUS/100),x(_.write.fbo),_.swap(),t.viewport(0,0,D,y),t.uniform1i(P.uniforms.uTarget,A.read.texId),t.uniform3f(P.uniforms.color,a.r,a.g,a.b),x(A.write.fbo),A.swap()}function multipleSplats(e,n=!1){for(let a=0;a<e;a++){const e=generateColor();e.r*=10,e.g*=10,e.b*=10;var r=canvas.width*Math.random(),t=canvas.height*Math.random(),i=1e3*(Math.random()-.5),o=1e3*(Math.random()-.5);n&&(r=canvas.width/2,t=canvas.height/2,i=1e3*(Math.random()-.5),o=1e3*(Math.random()-.5)),splat(r,t,i,o,e)}}function resizeCanvas(){canvas.width==canvas.clientWidth&&canvas.height==canvas.clientHeight||(canvas.width=canvas.clientWidth,canvas.height=canvas.clientHeight,initFramebuffers())}update();var my_dx=0,my_dy=0,my_color=generateColor();function generateColor(){let e=HSVtoRGB(Math.random(),1,1);return e.r*=.15,e.g*=.15,e.b*=.15,e}function getRandomInt(e,n){return e=Math.ceil(e),n=Math.floor(n),Math.floor(Math.random()*(n-e+1))+e}function HSVtoRGB(e,n,r){let t,i,o,a,u,v,l,f;switch(v=r*(1-n),l=r*(1-(u=6*e-(a=Math.floor(6*e)))*n),f=r*(1-(1-u)*n),a%6){case 0:t=r,i=f,o=v;break;case 1:t=l,i=r,o=v;break;case 2:t=v,i=r,o=f;break;case 3:t=v,i=l,o=r;break;case 4:t=f,i=v,o=r;break;case 5:t=r,i=v,o=l}return{r:t,g:i,b:o}}canvas.addEventListener("mousemove",e=>{splat(e.offsetX,e.offsetY,5*(e.offsetX-my_dx),5*(e.offsetY-my_dy),my_color),my_dx=e.offsetX,my_dy=e.offsetY}),setInterval(function(){my_color=generateColor()},500),canvas.addEventListener("touchmove",e=>{e.preventDefault();const r=e.targetTouches;for(let e=0;e<r.length;e++){let t=n[e];t.moved=t.down,t.dx=8*(r[e].pageX-t.x),t.dy=8*(r[e].pageY-t.y),t.x=r[e].pageX,t.y=r[e].pageY}},!1),canvas.addEventListener("touchstart",e=>{e.preventDefault();const r=e.targetTouches;for(let e=0;e<r.length;e++)e>=n.length&&n.push(new pointerPrototype),n[e].id=r[e].identifier,n[e].down=!0,n[e].x=r[e].pageX,n[e].y=r[e].pageY,n[e].color=generateColor()}),window.addEventListener("mouseup",()=>{n[0].down=!1}),window.addEventListener("touchend",e=>{const r=e.changedTouches;for(let e=0;e<r.length;e++)for(let t=0;t<n.length;t++)r[e].identifier==n[t].id&&(n[t].down=!1)}),window.addEventListener("keydown",n=>{"p"===n.key&&(e.PAUSED=!e.PAUSED)})}
```

Comment: Вы пробовали читать красный текст, который появляется под редактором, когда вставляешь ссылку на jsfiddle? https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sx8O7.png Код в первую очередь должен быть в самом вопросе, ссылка на сторонние ресурсы может быть только дополнением к вопросу.

Comment: Нужно добавить сам код в вопрос. Не ссылку на код, не скриншот кода, а именно код.

Comment: Так правильнее будет?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.text-take {
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 9;
  font-size: 80px;
  pointer-events: none;  <---
}
```

Comment: Спасибо друг, реально выручил!

Comment: @ПеревозчикиГусей Пожалуйста. Знак "галочка" - слева от ответа.

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]